# React - component in seperate script does not work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to learn react.js, but got stuck on "Hello World" script.

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="src/helloworld.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and src/helloworld.js:

```
React.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

When I put this code inside `<script>` in `index.html` file it works fine, but when I move it to seperate file I get blank page, and console error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/marcin/Projects/react/src/helloworld.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get that error because:

1. You have loaded the `index.html` from your local file system (e.g. by double clicking on it), instead of loading it via a web server
2. The JSX transformer, the one responsible of `text/jsx` scripts is a javascript component that tries to fetch the file specified by the `src` attribute of the `script` tag
3. Javascript is allowed to fetch external resources only from the protocols enumerated in the error message (and even for those has further limitation like cross-domain requess); files loaded from the local file system have the `file://` protocol which is not within that list.

When you included the `jsx` script in the `index.html` file it worked as no requests were needed in order to retrieve the `jsx` script.

What you need to do is grab your hands on a web server, place the hello world files into the document root of that server, and load them from the web server, e.g. from an URL like `http://localhost/index.html`.

Comment: is there any way to solve this without needing a server? I see many answers saying you need a server but the questions are usually about being able to run the js code in the browser. if I wanted, for instance, to include the result of a project created with create-react-app as a static page in another project, not a whole app

Comment: @raquelhortab if you can get past issue #3 from my answer, then you might be able to get away without a server

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you boot up a web server.

This `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` will boot up a simple web server.

You can run this in your directory. Access it here `http://localhost:8000`.

Or, you can use Chrome flags and add this line `--allow-file-access-from-files`

*Notes*

1. Python come pre-packaged with an OSX installation, so if you're on a Mac, good.
2. Chrome flags is not recommended as it is tedious of a process.

Comment: Python 3 syntaxis would be helpful as well: `python3 -m http.server [PORT]`

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is already approved but for reference I post code here. We can use react.js with script task like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
      document.getElementById('example')
    );
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```