# How to use react libraries in separate React component script?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to render react components from an html page. I referenced the question [React - component in seperate script does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200028/react-component-in-seperate-script-does-not-work) and loaded the html file from a URL like http://localhost/index.html.
My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <script src="https://...fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
           <script src="https://...fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
           <div id="example"></div>
           <script type="text/jsx" src="index.js"></script>
       </body>
   </html>
```

My index.js:

```
 ReactDOM.render(<MainPage />, document.getElementById('example'))
```

The error is that MainPage is not defined. But when I write

```
include MainPage
```

There is an error on the include statement. Also, how can i include other React libraries like 'Tabs' from react-tabs?

Comment: `0.13.3` yikes!

Comment: Hope you're not intending to use this in production

Answer (score 1):

If you `index.js` which is loaded inside your `html` contains `<MainPage />`, that means you did not compile your code. Browsers do not support `text/jsx` natively.

In order to use react with JSX you will need to use a compiler / bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As you are just learning React.Js for the first time, please consider [@Kapil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46110040/109941):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
      document.getElementById('example')
    );
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```